# Adding items to hash table in c++ gives access violation exception

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a hashtable of a set of numbers. This I am doing in procedural programming in C++. Here is my code:

// Following struct is defined globally

```
struct edgePixel{
    int row;
    int col;
    int intensity;
    edgePixel *nextPixel;
};

void Function1 (....other parameters not related to hashtable....){

// Declare and initialize hashtable
edgePixel **edgePixelTable = new edgePixel*[fileCounter];

   for(int i = 0; i<fileCounter; i++){
       edgePixelTable[i] = new edgePixel;
       edgePixelTable[i]->row = -1;
       edgePixelTable[i]->col = -1;
       edgePixelTable[i]->intensity = -1;
       edgePixelTable[i]->nextPixel = NULL;     
    }
    function2(..., index, &edgePixelTable);
}

void function2(..., int index, edgePixel ***edgePixelhistogram){
//Calculations of row, col, intensity and index
//......
//......
    addPixel(row, col, intensity, index, edgePixelhistogram);
}

void addPixel(int row, int col, int intensity, int fileID, edgePixel ***edgePixelTable){

    if (edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->row == -1){ //<--- Access violation happens right here
       edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->row = row;
       edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->col = col;
       edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->intensity = intensity;
       edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->nextPixel = NULL;
    }
    else{
       edgePixel *tempPtr = edgePixelTable[fileID];
       edgePixel *newNode = new edgePixel;
       newNode->row = row;
       newNode->col = col;
       newNode->intensity = intensity;
       newNode->nextPixel = NULL;
       while(tempPtr->nextPixel!=NULL){
          tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPixel;
       }
       tempPtr->nextPixel = newNode;
    }
```

I really do not know how to figure why and how the Access Violation error occurring. I pointed it out as a comment in the code. I encountered this when I was debugging the program. Also the way I am accessing the pointer element in the array looks weird. I think I am not doing it right. All I am trying to do is create an array of null pointers which is really the head of the linked lists at each index.

Can you please help me do this correctly? I am pretty sure I am doing pointer arithmetic wrong somewhere. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: We can't work with code "something like this". Please post a [mcve]. And note that C and C++ are different languages. Please pick only the one your are really writing code for.

Comment: "I really do not know how to figure out this problem" ... what problem ? which line ? what's the error message ?

Comment: I tried editing my question to make it more clear. There is an access violation I am getting when trying to read location in the hashtable.

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags. C is not C++ is not C. 2) Don't write such code in C++. Use the language features to provide good abstractions. 3) Being a 3-star C-programmer is not a compliment. This becomes worse for C++.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`edgePixelTable[fileID][0]->row` should become `(*edgePixelTable)[fileID]->row`

You pass the address of the table, so you need to dereference it before accessing it. This is because `edgePixelTable` is of type `edgePixel***` and points to a single element of type `edgePixel**`. When you do `edgePixelTable[fileID]` you reference way past the memory is actually points to.

So your seg fault is the result of your code having undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried what you said here. But it gives me illegal indirection error. Could you tell why that might be?